# Should I use boolean fields or state_machine gem in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, boolean

I have a e-mail system and I want that an user can decide with checkboxes what message want receive when happen determinate events, e.g.

```
field :when_receive_order, :type => Boolean, :default => "true"
field :when_accept_order, :type => Boolean, :default => "true"
field :when_cancel_order, :type => Boolean, :default => "true"
field :when_reject_order, :type => Boolean, :default => "true"
.
.
.
more...
```

I want to know **if is good use `Boolean` values or use [state_machine gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) in these case.**

In this link http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2012/10/10/booleans-are-baaaaaaaaaad/ is  argued that `Boolean` values are bad. So I make this question.

Note: My database is mongodb and my odm es mongoid

Comment: Humm, I don't understand... Should the "true" value be right where? As a DB-stored value? as an HTML-form field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one of those boolean values to be true at all times, you can use state_machine. Otherwise, you cannot.

In your case, I think it is possible that more than one values could be true. What if a user want to receive mails both when an order is accepted and when an order is canceled? So you cannot use state_machine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have not yet clear which is the best option

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a correct answer.. state machine can also serve multiple state fields..

Comment: Do you mean multiple state machines by multiple state fields? Or please tell me how to define multiple state fields for one state machine.

Comment: @Lichtamberg Yeaahh this is the question. How define multiple state fields/attributes for one state machine?. I can define a state machine for each field/attribute but is neccessary 2 or more state machine in model. Can you add a example with code? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how to define multiple state attributes for one state machine. And I think it's overkill to define a state machine for each boolean attributes. So state_machine might not be the solution for this case.

Comment: I working on this now, with state_machine best way here is to make event for each bool. Because each event have multiple states. If you merge all in one event code can be unreadable...

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this kind of configuration of your entities leads easily to errors... You should rely on this gem or maybe look at its sourcecode and implement it yourself..

Comment: Thank you very much! I have not yet clear which is the best option